# Animated GIF on custom Chromecast receiver

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, gif, chromecast, animated

I'm trying to display animated gifs on my custom HTML5 Chromecast receiver, and the gifs seem to be skipping a lot of frames due to limitations on the Chromecast device.

I've tried extracting each frame in the animated gif and creating an mp4 by stitching the pngs together using ImageMagick and ffmpeg:
`convert image.gif image%05d.png`
then `ffmpeg -i image%05d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p image.mp4` The image still jumps everytime the sequence loops (I used html5 video tag with loop option to play this)

Anybody have had any workarounds for displaying animated gifs on the Chromecast app?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to manually display each image frame at a time.